# How to access admin panel without login in drupal

Tags: javascript, html, drupal

I have created a custom theme in Drupal and it is a one page website. I have added region user account menu in footer. But I forgot to add region primary admin access.

Unfortunately I clicked on logout button and I am not able to login to admin. The page `example.com/user/login` shows empty.

Now how can I access the admin page of Drupal?

Comment: did you try admin/config ??

Comment: Tried but it also showing empty.

Comment: look here https://www.drupal.org/node/200774 
i think, espacially "Method 2: Change the active theme in the database" will help you!

Comment: If you do not have delete all core theme, try to go in you Drupal database, table "system", put the status of your theme to 0, and put themes/seven/seven.info status to 1. Then access admin/config. If this not work, try the same with themes/garland/garland.info et access to user/login.

Comment: I am Using drupal 8 and couldn't find system tabel

Comment: it is not working. Please give another tips

Comment: In drupal 8 database, where can i change the theme njame

Comment: Try to go /user/login page

Comment: use drush to change default theme : drush vset theme_default seven && drush en seven -y

Answer (score 1):

You change your default theme in setting.php.Uncomment this line in your setting.php file

```
 $conf['theme_default'] = 'garland';
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8+ use:

```
drush theme:enable bartik
drush config-set system.theme default bartik
```